# Equivalent Context-Free Grammars

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am having trouble understanding and pointing out when two different context-free grammars are structurally *equivalent* (at a very basic level).  What are some clues/hints I should look for when determining if two CFG's are *equivalent* or not?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining whether two CFGs are equivalent is an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Undecidable_problems), so *in general* there is no good way to assert the equality of two CFGs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what you mean by equivalence "structurally (at a very basic level)".

The well-known [undecidability result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Undecidable_problems) concerns what is also called **weak equivalence**: Two grammars are equivalent if and only if they generate the same language (= set of words).

Undecidability means that there exists no general algorithm that solves *every* instance of this problem. Individual instances may still be easy to solve (and you can probably think of examples).

In fact, there is a large *subclass* of the context-free languages for which weak equivalence is decidable: the **deterministic context-free** languages. Unfortunately, existance of an algorithm in this case does not mean that the algorithm is efficient.

However, if by structural equivalence you mean something like "only renaming nonterminals" or "generating parse trees of the same shape", this may be a [simpler problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000068800376).